# Changing color and bullets in Beamer's table of contents

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, color

Does anyone know how to change the color scheme and/or bullets used in Beamer's table of contents (without changing the overall structure color or theme)?  Unfortunately, the following doesn't work:

```
\setbeamertheme{enumerate item}[default]
\setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{black}
```

I would even be fine removing the numbering altogether.

Comment: The numbering in the TOC depends on the theme: the default theme doesn't use bullets, "Berlin" uses square bullets, "Madrid" circle bullets. Please tell us at least your theme or post a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: I've written a custom theme that's based on PaloAlto.  I should clarify that I don't mean bullets, per se.  The default symbols used for enumeration items in this theme are spheres with numbers inside them.  I know how to suppress this within regular enumerate environments, but I can't get the same trick to work in the TOC.

Comment: Maybe the problem was that `ball` and `sphere` lead to the same sphere-ish result as do `elephant` or any other un-defined string. Either `ball` or `sphere` are not defined and since sphere/ball is the theme-standard, it will fall back on this when given a undefined value.
`circle` and `square` work like expected and `default` removes the numbers altogether. Thanks to Kristen and Alan, I had the same problem before I came here!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Modify font/color of the element *section number projected*. An example doing some changes, not necessarily beautiful but demonstrating:

```
\setbeamerfont{section number projected}{%
  family=\rmfamily,series=\bfseries,size=\normalsize}
\setbeamercolor{section number projected}{bg=black,fg=yellow}
```

With PaloAlto theme:

[image]

Before, PaloAlto default:

[image]

Comment: This almost works.  Do you know how to change the sphere to, say, a ball?  `\setbeamertemplate{sections in toc}[ball]` is not working.

Comment: `\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[ball]` works for me. Besides `ball`, there's `circle` and `square`.

Comment: @Kristen It should be `{section in toc}` (singular not plural)

Comment: @Alan I've tried singular as well.  Still not working, but I am about to strangle my PC!

Comment: @Kristen Then there's something else going on with your document (unless you have an old version of beamer.) If you create a two-frame document with a table of contents and one frame, with the `setbeamertemplate` command, does it work?

Comment: @Alan No, it does not work.  I'm still getting spheres.  A more helpful solution to my problem would be to get rid of the markers altogether.  I'd like the TOC to either have the form of a simple enumerate environment (with just numbers; no balls, spheres, etc.), or simply be listed sections/subsections with no marker at all.  I know that some of the other themes have this look.

Comment: I just realized that \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[default] will remove the markers altogether...so nevermind!!  Thanks!