# Change the color of table of contents in beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, color

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8043/change-the-background-color-of-a-frame-in-beamer) discusses how to change the colour of a frame in beamer. You must add a setting outside the frame using `{...}`. This solution doesn't work for the table of contents. MWE below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}     
\usetheme{default}

\AtBeginSection[]{
    % with this one both are yellow
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=yellow} 
    \begin{frame}
    % with this one both are white
    %\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=yellow} 
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \vfill
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \vfill
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{This should be yellow}

\begin{frame}

This should be white

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

How can I achieve what is needed? [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8011/changing-color-and-bullets-in-beamers-table-of-contents) doesn't help either.

One solution I found is adding the table of content slide manually, using:

```
{
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=yellow} 
    \frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}
}
```

But if I have a many sections, is there a way to automate the above to all ToC frames?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original code will work if you add an extra pair of `{}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}     
\AtBeginSection{
    {
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=yellow} 
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \vfill
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \vfill
    \end{frame}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\section{This should be yellow}

\begin{frame}    
This should be white
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]